# How to add nodes inside an XML with incremented names using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Given below code is used to call the form for adding validation by right clicking on the context menu that i have in my WPF application.

```
public void AddValidation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidationForm obj = new ValidationForm();
            ProcessGrid.Content = obj.VForm;
        }
```

It will open the validation form. After entering the required details, when i click on submit button given inside the form, it will create a xml like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Processes>
  <Process Name="Process1" Namespace="" Methodname="">
    <Validations IsSelected="True" />
       <validation>xsdPath</validation>
    <Validations>
</Process>
</Processes>
```

If i will again add any new validation then it will again add a node in this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Processes>
  <Process Name="Process1" Namespace="" Methodname="">
    <Validations IsSelected="True" />
       <validation>xsdPath</validation>
       <validation>xsdPath1</validation>
    <Validations>
</Process>
</Processes>
```

For creating XML, i have used the following code.
string MyValue;

```
MyValue = Pages.ProcessesLayoutList.MyValue;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\562630\Desktop\New folder\ProcessComplete.xml");
var a = doc.Descendants("Process").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == MyValue).
Select(x => x.Element("Validations")).FirstOrDefault();
a.Add(new XElement("Validation", s));
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\562630\Desktop\New folder\ProcessComplete.xml");
```

But, i want to add  node with incremented names like  then  and so on.So, After adding validation nodes each and every time, it should add validation node in incremental order. Please suggest some way to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on `Count` of elements to maintain value sequence for newly added elements, please note this approach works only if you add elements synchronously.

```
var count = 
        doc.Descendants("Validations")
        .Elements()
        .Count();

// Use count to maintain incremental value for your newly added elements.   
doc.Descendants("Validations")
        .First()
        .Add(new XElement("validation", string.Format("xsdPath{0}", count)));
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/weSDoX)

Comment: Code shown *does not* demonstrate adding nodes with  incremented names... Node value is not node name... Consider updating answer or question.

Comment: It does @AlexeiLevenkov, first statement we are calculating the elements count and in the second statement we are using that count while adding the element.

Comment: All nodes your code adds have the same *name* ("validation"), but different values. I understand that you are trying to answer using the same words OP is using, but I think it is not a good approach for SO answer.

Comment: I got you, yes it should be incremental values (_not_ the names).